# Unable to create a relationship with spring data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to create a set of CRUD REST APIs for Neo4j. Everything works fine except I am unable to create a new relationship. These are the entities:

```
@Node("Movie")
@Getter @Setter  @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    //@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long id;

    @Property("title")
    private String title;

    @Property("description")
    private String description;

    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private List<Roles actorsAndRoles;

    @Relationship(type = "DIRECTED", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private List<Person directors;
}

 @Node("Person")
 @Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
 public class Person {
 
     @Id @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;
 
     @Property("name")
     private String name;
 
     @Property("born")
     private String born;
 
 }

 @Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
 @RelationshipProperties
 public class Roles{
 
     @RelationshipId
     private Long id;
 
     @TargetNode
     private Person person;
 
     @Property("roles")
     private List<String roles;
 }
```

This is the controller (the class is called MovieController) method I am calling:

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Movie movie){
        try {
            movie.setId(null);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(movieService.save(movie));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have uploaded the code here: https://github.com/RosarioB/spring-boot-crud-rest-api-neo4j/tree/basic_crud

This is an example of a body of a POST request at: http://localhost:8080/api/movies

```
{
    
   "title":"Matrix",
   "description":"Science fiction",
   "actorsAndRoles":[
       {
           "person":{
               "name":"Keanu Reeves",
               "born":"27-01-1963"
           }
       }
   ]
   

}
```

And this is the response:

```
{
    "id": 16,
    "title": "Matrix",
    "description": "Science fiction",
    "actorsAndRoles": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "person": {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Keanu Reeves",
                "born": "27-01-1963"
            },
            "roles": null
        }
    ],
    "directors": null
}
```

Unfortunately on the database only the 2 nodes (one Person and one Movie)  got created but not the relationship. I would have expected the relationship ACTED_IN to be created too.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Spring Data Neo4j. You can add the below section of code to the configuration/SpringBootApplication class. Information on the issue is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2728). It should be fixed once the updated release is published.

```
@Bean
public Configuration cypherDslConfiguration() {
    return Configuration.newConfig()
        .withDialect(Dialect.NEO4J_5)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: also, some info in here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/getting-started.html#configure-cypher-dsl-dialect